# name of this shape [3d solid]

Tags: solid-geometry

what is the name of this 3d solid please?

[image]

"faces" of 3 and 4 sides.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [cuboctahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron).

$${ }$$

Answer (score 2):

It's called cuboctahedron.

Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiregular_polyhedron .